# How to Add a Product to Magento 2 REST API using C#?

Tags: c#, api, magento2, magento2.1

How to create a new product to magento 2.1 programmatically  using c#.
Whenever I run my code I get this exception but I cannot understand the meaning:

```
main.CRITICAL: LogicException: 
    Property "0" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface". in C:\wamp64\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Reflection\NameFinder.php:100
    Stack trace:

#0 C:\wamp64\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Reflection\NameFinder.php(59): Magento\Framework\Reflection\NameFinder->findAccessorMethodName(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\ClassReflection), '0', 'get0', 'is0')

#1 C:\wamp64\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor.php(158): Magento\Framework\Reflection\NameFinder->getGetterMethodName(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\ClassReflection), '0')

#2 C:\wamp64\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor.php(322): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->_createFromArray('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)

#3 C:\wamp64\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor.php(119): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->convertValue(Array, 'Magento\\Catalog...')

#4 C:\wamp64\www\Magento\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver.php(101): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->process('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save', Array)

#5 C:\wamp64\www\Magento\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(299): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve()

#6 C:\wamp64\www\Magento\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()

#7 C:\wamp64\www\Magento\var\generation\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#8 C:\wamp64\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#9 C:\wamp64\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#10 C:\wamp64\www\Magento\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Please ask well formatted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception means that you're trying to set a property of the object that does not exist in the product.

why are you trying to set the fields created_at and updated_at? These are automatically filled by Magento as soon as you create your product.

You should print out the request you're sending and compare the resulting JSON with the swagger list of rest api calls [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html)

Comment: you are correct,there is an mismatch. It is working fine after fixing mismatch in request. tq sissy..

Comment: glad to help, would be great if you can accept the answer. thank you